# Vue - Render new component based on page count

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, conditional-rendering

I'm working on an onboarding process that will collect a users name, location, job , etc.
It needs to be one question per page but as an SPA so I currently have around 20 components to conditionally render.

Atm, I have a counter and Prev/Next buttons that decrease/increase the counter respectively. I'm then using `v-if` to check what number the counter is on and render the appropriate page.

**Is there a better way around this that is less repetitive and bulky?**

Any ideas appreciated!

```
data() {
   return {
      onboardingStep: 0,
   }
},
methods: {
   prevStep() {
      this.onboardingStep -= 1;
   },
   nextStep() {
      this.onboardingStep += 1;
   }
}
```

```
<intro-step v-if="onboardingStep === 0"></intro-step>
<first-name v-if="onboardingStep === 1"></first-name>
<last-name v-if="onboardingStep === 2"></last-name>

...etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Suggestion :***

You can make your `field` components to show or hide based on the `prev`/`next` state. Dynamic components provide that platform in an efficient and simple way.

Syntax **:**

```
<component :is="componentName"></component>
```

Then, You can create each component instance dynamically by putting a watcher on `components` array.

```
watch: {
  components: {
    handler() {
      this.components.forEach(cName => {
        Vue.component(cName, { 
          template: `template code will come here` 
        })
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      components: [],
      onboardingStep: 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.components = ['intro-step', 'first-name', 'last-name'];
  },
  watch: {
    components: {
      handler() {
        this.components.forEach(cName => {
          Vue.component(cName, { 
                data() {
                return {
                modelName: cName
              }
            },
            template: '<input type="text" v-model="modelName"/>'
          })
        });
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    prevStep() {
      this.onboardingStep -= 1;
    },
    nextStep() {
      this.onboardingStep += 1;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(cName, index) in components" :key="index">
      <component :is="cName" v-if="index === onboardingStep"></component>
  </div>
  
  <button @click="prevStep" :disabled="onboardingStep < 1">Prev</button>
  <button @click="nextStep" :disabled="onboardingStep === components.length - 1">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to Vue and haven't come across :is before so I'll look into this more

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with all your component names in the right order.

```
const components = ['intro-step', 'first-name', 'last-name' ]
```

And then with a v-for loop set all the components in your template:

```
<template v-for="(component, index) in components" :key="component">
    <component :is="component" v-if="index === onboardingStep">
</template>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to Vue and haven't come across :is before so I'll look into this more