# Vue Composition API with "is" attribute for conditional rendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm working on an onboarding process that will collect a users name, location, job , etc. It needs to be one question per page but as an SPA so I currently have around 20 components to conditionally render.

Same problem as this but I've been asked change to Composition API and now I can't get this to work.
[Vue - Render new component based on page count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72858778/vue-render-new-component-based-on-page-count/72865380#72865380)

The solution in the above was to make an array with all the page titles, a `for` loop and use `:is` to render each page as needed.

My components are named in this format: `MLandingPage.vue`, `MFirstName.vue`, etc.
I also have buttons that add or minus 1 from `onboardingStep` to go forward or back a step.

I have tried this:

```
const onboardingPages = ref(["MLandingPage", "MFirstName", 'MWelcome', 'MLastName', 'MAge' ]);
const onboardingStep = ref(0);
```

```
<template v-for="(onboardingPage, index) in onboardingPages" :key="index">
      <component :is="onboardingPage" v-if="index === onboardingStep"/>
</template>
```

This doesn't render anything on the page and when I inspect, it just has `<mlandingpage></mlandingpage>` with no content.

I tried this instead:

```
const onboardingPages = ref(["m-landing-page", "m-first-name", 'm-welcome', 'm-last-name', 'm-age' ]);
```

Still nothing and I get this when I inspect the page: `<m-landing-page></m-landing-page>`

As a test, if I just write `<m-landing-page></m-landing-page>` in the code, it works.

Totally new to Composition API and the "is" attribute so any help would be great.

Edit - added more code for context:

```
<script setup>
import MLandingPage from "~~/components/onboarding/MLandingPage.vue";
import MFirstName from "~/components/onboarding/MFirstName.vue";
import MLastName from "~/components/onboarding/MLastName.vue";
import MAge from "~/components/onboarding/MAge.vue";

import { ref } from "vue";

const onboardingPages = ref(["m-landing-page", "m-first-name", 'm-welcome', 'm-last-name', 'm-age' ]);
const onboardingStep = ref(0);
function prevStep() {
  onboardingStep.value -= 1;
}
function nextStep() {
  onboardingStep.value += 1;
}
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-end gap-2 md:gap-10 mt-16 px-5 md:px-20">

    <h1>Example Page Title</h1>

    <div class="mt-16 p-5 pr-8 md:px-20 md:mt-24">
      <template v-for="(onboardingPage, index) in onboardingPages" :key="index">
        <component :is="onboardingPage" v-if="index === onboardingStep"/>
      </template>
    </div>

    <button @click="prevStep">Back</button>
    <button @click="nextStep">Next</button>

  </div>
</template>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what's the rest of the component. The thing that may matter is script setup syntax Basically, use the component and not its name where possible

Comment: Do you import the components you want to render in the main one where you use the `:is` attribute?

Comment: Apologies, added more code for context.  Not really sure what you mean by using the component instead of the name. Can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: You can put a Component in the `:is` property, instead of a string value. A string is generally assumed to be an HTMLElement. You could make a `computed` for a onboardingPageComponent that returns the correct Component declaration that you'd normally register under `components` in Vue2 (the import at the top, or as async function).

Answer (score 0):

Found a much simpler way around this

Key issue was that I had the page names as strings

```
const onboardingPages = ref([MLandingPage, MFirstName, MWelcome, MLastName, MAge]);
```

```
<div class="mt-16 p-5 pr-8 md:px-20 md:mt-24">
  <transition name="fade">
      <component :is="onboardingPages[onboardingStep]"  />
  </transition>
</div>
```